# Populate MOSS2010 pages with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to populate a MOSS 2010 installation with complete pages. We have a custom development based on MOSS and, given that we are using Agile development, we reinstall the whole solution at the end of every sprint. To properly test the solution at each iteration I need to have different types of pages and items available. Currently I recreate them by hand, but this gets a little tedious. I'm hoping therefore to create a powershell script so that I can automatically populate the solution with pages (custom models), and other custom list items (user defined links, etc).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

ravloony

Comment: What else do you have in pages other than list items?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly populate list items using the object model via powershell in a similar manner to how you'd do it via C# object model code.

Here's an example: http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2008/02/26/PowerShellSharePointAddAListItem.aspx